# Novell OES 2 User Login / Logout logging/tracking

Tags: logging, login, sles, novell, logoff

Currently we're running OES 2.0.1 / SLES 10.2 and I'm trying to figure out how to track when users log in and out of the system. I've been googling around for a couple hours and all I can find is that Novell discontinued an addin that would do this back in '09.

So the question: How can I track user login/logout times in OES 2 / SUSE 10.2?

EDIT: Sorry, I need to be able to track logins via the Novell Client/NDS, these users don't actually have linux logins associated with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to track logouts, but we track login times on our Suse servers by adding this to /etc/profile.local:

```
# Set current date/time
CURRTIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%T`

echo $CURRTIME >> /usr/local/logins/$USER
```

So if you logged in as user **ernie** for example, it will create a file called /usr/local/logins/ernie that contains a line for each login time for that user.

/etc/profile.local is used to set environment variables, etc... whenever a user logs in, so you can put code in there that you want fired each time a user logs in.

You can tweak `$CURRTIME` to get the date format you need.  `$USER` is a default environment variable with the user's name.  You'll need to create the /usr/local/logins directory or whatever directory you want to dump login "tracking files" to.

Comment: This does work for linux logins, sorry I wasnt specific in my initial question.